# How to implement pre-training in Tensorflow? How to partially use saved weights from checkpoint file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, transfer-learning

**For the convenience of discussion, the following models have been simplified.**

Let's say there are around 40,000 512x512 images in my training set. I am trying to implement pre-training, and my plan is the following:

1.Train a neural network (lets call it net_1) that takes in 256x256 images, and save the trained model in tensorflow checkpoint file format.

```
net_1: input -> 3 conv2d -> maxpool2d -> 2 conv2d -> rmspool -> flatten -> dense
```

let's call this structure net_1_kernel:

```
net_1_kernel: 3 conv2d -> maxpool2d -> 3 conv2d
```

and call the remaining part other_layers:

```
other_layers: rmspool -> flatten -> dense
```

Thus we can represent net_1 in the following form:

```
net_1: input -> net_1_kernel -> other_layers
```

2.Insert several layers to the structure of net_1, and now call it net_2. It should look like this:

```
net_2: input -> net_1_kernel -> maxpool2d -> 3 conv2d -> other_layers
```

net_2 will take 512x512 images as input.

**When I train net_2, I would like to use the saved weights and biases in the checkpoint file of net_1 to initialize the net_1_kernel part in net_2. How can I do this?**

I know that I can load checkpoints to make predictions of test data. But in that case it will load everything (net_1_kernel and other_layers). What I want is to load net_1_kernel only and use it for the weight/bias initialization in net_2.

I also know that I can print contents in checkpoint files to txt, and copy & paste to manually initialize the weights and biases. However, there are so many numbers in those weights and biases, and this would be my last choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can use the following code to check the list of all checkpoints in the ckpt file you saved.

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import inspect_checkpoint as chkp
chkp.print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name="file.ckpt", tensor_name="xxx", all_tensors=False, all_tensor_names=True)
```

Remember when you restore a checkpoint file, it will restore all variables in the checkpoint file. If you have to save and restore specific variables, you can do so as follows:

1. Make a list of all variables you want to save from `tf.trainable_variables()`

`var = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if "net_1_kernel" in v.name]`

`saverAndRestore = tf.train.Saver(var)`

2. Now you can easily save or restore all the variables in var list as follows:

`saverAndRestore.save(sess_1,"net_1.ckpt")`

This will only save variables in the list var to net_1.ckpt.

`saverAndRestore.restore(sess_1,"net_1.ckpt")`

This will only restore variables in the list var from net_1.ckpt.

Apart from above, all you have to do is name/scope your variables such that you can easily do step 1 above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want is to restore the "var" as you created above into another net (net_2). Do you mean I can restore var in net_1.ckpt into net_2 as long as they have the same variable name?

Comment: Yes, as long as they have same name/scope, you can restore as shown above.